# new Geocoder(this).getFromLocationName("taj mahal", 1) not returning result neither giving any exception

Tags: android

not getting size of list>0 ,I am  using geocoder.
Is it neceesary to have premium plan of googleMap for android to use geocoder?

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
      /* mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 15);
        mMap.moveCamera(update);
*/
        try {
            pinaddress();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("errorrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr");
        }



    }

    private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lon, float zoom) {
        LatLng l1 = new LatLng(lat, lon);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(l1, zoom);
        mMap.moveCamera(update);
    }

    private void pinaddress() throws IOException {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> list;

        list = geocoder.getFromLocationName("taj mahal", 1);

        if (list.size() > 0) {
            Address address = list.get(0);
            String locality = address.getLocality();
            System.out.println("locality" + locality);
            Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            double lat = address.getLatitude();
            double lon = address.getLongitude();
            gotoLocation(lat, lon, 15);
        } else
            Toast.makeText(this, "checkout connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

the commented part in onmapready shows correct on map with marker
 but using geocoder its list size=0 and
on screen only shows map 
and output

```
03-16 13:03:42.522 24772-24843/com.jagdiv.android.myapplicationmap D/Volley: [370] a.a: HTTP response for request=<[ ] https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api 0x99e6744e NORMAL 1> [lifetime=5290], [size=47], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
03-16 13:03:42.522 24772-24772/com.jagdiv.android.myapplicationmap D/Volley: [1] l.b: 5290 ms: [ ] https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api 0x99e6744e NORMAL 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says-

> Returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no
>   backend service available.

Many suggests a polling concept and it works for many of us (I agree that drains out our api limit but there are ways to overcome this to some extent implementing some caching techniques at your side) -

```
try {
    int attempt=10;
    List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocationName("taj mahal", 1);
    while (list.size()==0 && attempt>0) {
        attempt--;
        list = geocoder.getFromLocationName("taj mahal", 1);
    }
    if (list.size()>0) {
        Address address = list.get(0);
            String locality = address.getLocality();
            System.out.println("locality" + locality);
            Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            double lat = address.getLatitude();
            double lon = address.getLongitude();
            gotoLocation(lat, lon, 15);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.print(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: should work. Don't you have play services installed in your avd?

Comment: even though i run same code on asnctask in doInBackground method its not  returning  list size>0

Comment: Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
                System.out.println("geocoder.isPresent()" + geocoder.isPresent()); its output is geocoder.isPresent() false